# Why were emergency responses so underwhelming in the 2011 attack in Norway?

Tags: terrorism, norway, state-of-emergency

Anders Breivik's terrorist attack on children at Utøya Island on 22 July, 2011 was an avoidable tragedy. Why was there no helicopter or adequate emergency response teams? It took several hours for a police response; the gunman himself called the police-twice and also got no response. Why was the Norwegian government so unprepared for a domestic terror event?

Comment: Did you do any research yourself? The Wikipedia page seems to have a fairly comprehensive answer to your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Norway_attacks#Rescue_and_emergency_response

Comment: @MartinTournoij  Of course I read the the wiki page and several news accounts as well. None of them address WHY the necessary resources were not available. A crew was on holiday? Why no back-up? Why no helicopter? Why no response or emergency plan from Orland Air Station? Wiki doesn’t cover these questions.

Comment: Why on hold? None of the responses so far have addressed the question WHY was the Norwegian government response so unprepared? All of the comments so far, appear defensive rather than answers. I wonder why the Norwegian govt was so unprepared for this emergency—not terrorism per se, but ANY emergency where govt needs to respond to protect people—it is a big part of the job of govt.

Comment: This post does not promote any “cause” or particular position other than government readiness for emergencies. I would ask that whomever voted for this “on hold” please state how this post is not in “good faith.”

Comment: `This post does not promote any “cause” or particular position other than government readiness for emergencies`: well, that's a position, no? ;-) I didn't close, but phasing such as "avoidable tragedy" and "underwhelming" don't sound very neutral.

Comment: My statements are OBSERVATIONS. I simply do understand how the govt. didn’t have an action plan to team up with military, or have an Action Plan for domestic terrorism or other emergency situation. You sound defensive Martin. Are you Norwegian?

Comment: You asked a question and I answered; that's not being defensive, that's doing you a favour.

Comment: You didn’t answer the question at all. You spoke to logistics and political decisions that affect a nation’s safety. Still no response about teaming up with the military. Also, no need to do me any “favors.”

Answer (score 7):

Because the expenses to provide

1. A transport helicopter.
2. A backup pilot for the surveillance helicopter.
3. A backup ferry.
4. A small boat on the lake owned by the police.
5. A backup security official for the one who was killed.
6. Enough phone operators to handle the call volume.
7. A plan for compensating for the lack of these things.

had been deemed unnecessary as they had never needed such a thing previously.

It is unclear how many people can fly on the surveillance helicopter.  It may be just a two seater or even a one seater.

Consider that the 9/11 attacks in the United States could have been prevented by a rule keeping the cockpit door locked even in the face of a threat to a flight attendant or passenger.  But they did not have such a rule in place on September 11th of 2001.  Planes as bombs had been previously described in a book by Tom Clancy, but no one saw the need to explicitly prevent them until after they occurred.

It's easy to say after the fact that such-and-such should have been available.  Before, the presumption is that things that have never happened aren't going to happen.  For example, in Germany, an attacker drove a truck through a crowd.  In response, large crowds (in Germany and elsewhere) are often protected by barriers that would keep someone from driving through.  But prior to that, such barriers did not seem necessary.  After all, what kind of demented idiot would deliberately drive through a crowd?  Yet a Dick Francis book (*Proof*) described such an act decades earlier.

I doubt that you will find what you want, as it is extremely unlikely that anyone made a deliberate choice to not have any of this equipment.  They had never really needed any of those things previously.  So they didn't provide them.

Transport helicopters are expensive to buy and operate.  [How Much Does a Helicopter Cost?](https://toughnickel.com/misc/How-much-does-a-Helicopter-cost) and [How Much Does a Helicopter Cost?](http://www.policehelicopterpilot.com/how-much-does-a-helicopter-cost/) suggest that a helicopter would have cost at least US$340,000 for three passengers (four seats including pilot).  Three not enough?  A twelve seater could be US$7 million.

Each pilot may go through [US$50,000](http://www.policehelicopterpilot.com/so-how-do-you-become-a-police-helicopter-pilot) in training.  And apparently you would need at least two pilots (if not three) in case one goes on vacation.  It may be difficult to hire someone who can pilot and do other things.  You may either have to pay extra or have a full time pilot even if you only need part time work.  This is also an on-call job, which costs extra.

[Operation expenses](http://helicopterforum.verticalreference.com/topic/12708-how-much-do-helicopter-cost-to-buy-and-run/) were about US$20,000 per year in one example.  Some of those are civilian expenses that may not apply to a police helicopter.  Note that expenses increase as the helicopter gets larger.  Expect that each pilot has to run the helicopter about that much to stay in practice.

With maintenance, you essentially have to buy a new helicopter every ten to twenty years (you may spend that maintaining the existing helicopter).  New rotors or engines are not cheap.  And you have to keep wear parts on hand.

A small boat would be cheaper, but you'd need one for every separate body of water.

Developing a plan often takes time and experimentation.  They would need to engage in activities as if responding to a crisis.  And of course, in a crisis, the situation might change.  In this case, the ferry boat was unavailable because it was on the island.  So they couldn't just take the ferry to the island.  That might not have been obvious when developing a plan.  And of course, their plans may not focus on small areas like islands with five hundred people only on certain days of the year.  They may be more focused on cities with hundreds of thousands of people.  Most cities are reachable by land.  The ones that aren't tend to maintain their own police force.

Even if they had a helicopter or boat, those things wouldn't have prevented the tragedy.  They might possibly have reduced it in scope.  Meanwhile, a couple armed volunteer deputies for the security officer might have actually stopped the incident when it was starting.

Example article about the [report claiming police could have acted faster](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-19241327).  This gives a timeline:

- 17:25 Police notified of shooting.
- 18:09 Team at the lake.
- 18:15 Could have reached the island, as per the commission.
- 18:27 Did reach the island (another [source](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-14260297) puts this at 18:25).

Even if we assume this is true, it suggests that they only could have saved twelve minutes in their response time.  The transport helicopter might have shaved some more time off that, assuming they could access it immediately (how long to get a pilot to the helicopter and the helicopter to meet the tactical response team?).  It's unclear how many people were killed during those twelve minutes.  Or ten minutes if the other source is correct.  Possibly less than that if the commission was overoptimistic in its timeline.

Frankly, this seems quite responsive to me.  Wasting ten minutes while trying to resolve a unique situation does not seem untoward.  They could have shaved off some time if they owned a multi-million dollar transport helicopter.  They could have flown straight from Oslo to the island.  But in most circumstances, that wouldn't have necessarily given them much of a boost over driving.  Hiring a couple extra officers might be more effective most of the time than a helicopter that is rarely needed.

Comment: Having been a Crew Chief and an Aircraft Maintenance Officer in the USAF over a 22 year career, I am well aware of the cost of aircraft and their maintenance. The RNAF has helicopters pilots; it seems an emergency services plan could be worked out. 911 comparisons are a false equivalency; hopefully we learn from our shortcomings. Adequate emergency response plans are govt. responsibility, having a rescue helicopter and back-up pilots are the norm.

Answer (score 4):

The police in Norway did not expect a terrorist incident because such things were, and are, extremely uncommon in that country. Wikipedia lists [three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrorism_in_Norway) lethal terror attacks in recent decades.

It is quite difficult to keep an organization prepared for high-impact, low-probability events that do not happen for decades. Ask yourself how your hometown would deal with a nuclear war, and what they do to prepare against homicidal [vending machines](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37000/are-americans-more-likely-to-be-killed-by-vending-machines-than-terrorist-refuge).

Comment: Any industrialized country SHOULD expect and prepare for terrorism in this day in age. It is the job of govt to prepare to respond to emergencies. Rarity of event is not an excuse. No one has addressed the lack of cooperation with RNAF; they have resources that were not used because no plan was made and no one thought to use them.

Comment: @M.Mat, if you look at the numbers, any country *should* prepare for an asteroid impact or a nuclear power plant disaster somewhere upwind from them, yet they don't. And the same money would probably save more people if it was put into an anti-smoking campaign. Terrorism risks, notably islamist terror, get high attention because it is about strangers deliberately inflicting harm, not self-inflicted harm like cancer.

Comment: Again, this is more deflection and false equivalency narratives that do not answer my question.

Comment: @M.Mat, I think I **did** answer the question. A government cannot prepare for all possible threats, it has to spend planning and preparation on likely threats. Norway made the judgement that terror was way down on the list of likely threats, based on solid historical patterns. You claim that "any industrialized country should ... expect terrorism" but that's just not true for any industrialized country. Some experience more of it, some less.

Comment: ‘...some more, some less.’ Yes, yet still doesn’t respond to an action plan with RNAF based on the general climate of tensions in Europe. I have repeatedly asked about THAT and have spoken of readiness for domestic terrorism; never mentioned Islamic radicalism. Every comment in this thread has refused to address the military angle and deflects to, “we can’t prepare for everything.” I have no axe to grind with current or past govts. of Norway, only questioning WHY what seems basic emergency readiness was ignored and perhaps what has been done, if anything, to correct emergency plans.

Comment: @M.Mat, and I said that there is a limited amount of time, attention, and money available to any government, and Norway had good reasons to put other things higher on the agenda. I would argue that that is still the case, even in hindsight. Sure, they could have had contingency plans for terror. But then the government wouldn't have done other things deemed more important. (By the way, you talk about a "general climate of tensions in Europe" and what is that supposed to mean other than islamist terror? Domestic terror doesn't appear that high on the radar Europe-wide.)

Comment: Still no answer to lack of cooperation with military. Repeating your previous “answer” doesn’t change that oversight.

Comment: @M.Mat, my answer is that a government cannot prepare for all thinkable contingencies, it has to look at likely ones. You start with the assumption that there **should have been** military support for the police and ask why it wasn't there. I start with the assumption that the military **should not** be used for law enforcement unless it is clear that the civilian police will be overwhelmed and all relevant procedures have been followed. On average, countries where the military plays an important role in law enforcement tend to be crappy ones.

Comment: Not ‘law enforcement’ emergency contingency plans. If law enforcement doesn’t have a helo, they should have have a plan to use other govt. resources like the military. It’s why the US has a National Guard—resources to call in if needed.

Comment: @M.Mat, I don't think that is a good characterization of the **origins** of the US National Guard. And in Europe there is widespread agreement that the military shouldn't be used for law enforcement, only to stack sandbags and hand out rations in case of flooding or the like. Being on call for transport would require the military to act domestically without a proper declaration of emergency. I think you should accept that many Europeans don't see a close integration of the police and the military as a good thing, and that there are very legitimate reasons to think so.

Comment: As a retired member of the United States Armed Services who has worked many times with National Guard components during domestic emergencies, it is a completely appropriate government response to use all resources needed to save lives. Posse Comitatus keeps every element deployed within Constitutional limits. Using RNAF resources to travel faster or deploy other needed resources already in govt. use is a prudent plan to deal with many UNFORESEEN events. The Norwegian govt. needs to have a plan as clearly demonstrated by the slow and deadly effects the response to this tragedy.

Comment: @M.Mat, Europe and the US have different concepts of law enforcement and security. Both have different adventages and disadvantages. If you cannot accept that not everyone thinks like you, this debate is pointless.

Comment: This isn’t personal or national for that matter. It’s about the safety and care of human lives and the government’s commitment to its citizens. We’re done here.

Comment: @Yes. Many people in Europe and elsewhere believe that there must be a firm line between the military (who *fight enemies*), the police (who *take suspects into custody*) and the intelligence agencies (who *collect information not admissible in court*). Security and liberty must be balanced, those who want one at the expense of the other will have neither. You might reflect on the downvotes and closure for your question ...

Comment: I believe you have no idea what I’m talking about. I believe a firm line between all facets of govt. must be adhered to but cooperation between agencies is essential to the ultimate aim of the well-being of citizens. I don’t  think that safety is at the cost of freedom and liberty.

Comment: @M.Mat, I think I understand what you are talking about. But *understanding* what you are talking about doesn't mean *accepting* it. The difference, I'm willing to consider that other parts of the world come to other value judgements, based on different historical experiences.